# One more blank line when to match string with awk's RF and RT?

Tags: bash, awk

I want to match all strings which begins with the character x.

[image]

Why

```
echo " x  x1 x2 y1 z1  x345" |awk -v RS="x[^ ]*" '$0=RT'
```

output one more blank line than

```
echo " x  x1 x2 y1 z1  x345" |awk -v RS="x[0-9 ]*" '$0=RT'
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^ ]` captures the new line, the other regex won't.  If you want to get the same results use `echo -n` to suppress the trailing new line.

Answer (score 1):

A newline is not the blank character so the last record is `x345\n`. The expression you really want is:

```
$ echo " x  x1 x2 y1 z1  x345" |awk -v RS="x[^[:space:]]*" '$0=RT'
x
x1
x2
x345
```

but of course you should never use `$0=RT` you should simply use `{print RT}` instead (or if you feel a burning need to reassign $0 and force field splitting to happen twice then `{$0=RT}1'`).